# Cannot see control on the right hand side of the UITableViewCell of a UITableViewController inside an UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am trying to show 2 `UITableViewController's` inside an horizontal `UIScrollView`. I am using `AUtoLayout` and `Size Classes`. My storyboards are of size `Inferred`. This is what I did for my test:

- Add an `UIScrollView` and choose `Update Constraints for AutoLayout` from `Resolve AutoLayout Issues`.
- Setup one `UITableViewController` and one `UIViewController` which inherits from `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` (I wanted to try both ways to use table views)
- For both of them I added an `UIButton` on the right hand side and for AutoLayout I choose top and trailing edge to be fixed on the right.

After I run the code for `UITableViewController` I can only the "n" from Button if I click on the cell, I can see the button.
For the `UIViewController` table view I don't see the button at all.

Here is a print screen:
[image]

And here is my code for the scroll view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

    let testTableVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TestTableViewController") as! TestTableViewController;
    let testVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TestViewController") as! TestViewController;

    var bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    var width = bounds.size.width
    var height = bounds.size.height;

    scrollView!.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2*width, height);


    let viewControllers = [testTableVC, testVC]

    var idx:Int = 0;


    for viewController in viewControllers {
        // index is the index within the array
        // participant is the real object contained in the array
        addChildViewController(viewController);
        let originX:CGFloat = CGFloat(idx) * width;
        viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(originX, 0, width, height);
        scrollView!.addSubview(viewController.view)
        viewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        idx++;
    }

}
```

edit:

https://github.com/adrianstanciu24/scrollviewtest

Comment: I'd say this is gonna be autolayout issue. You create `TestTableViewController` and `TestViewController`, but you don't add any constraints for the scroll view. Do you have the project hosted somewhere public?

Comment: https://github.com/adrianstanciu24/scrollviewtest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created pull request that solves this. What was wrong is that you've used default `UITableViewCell` and added some custom content to it in storyboard. Table view then dequeued the default cell and drawn the default cell atop of the one from storyboard (with margins on sides - so only right part of your button was visible). You need to create custom `UITableViewCell`, connect outlets and dequeue the custom cell, the default one doesn't know anything about your button.

Comment: Its working, but for my real project it is still not working. I was already using custom cell, maybe its a different issue.

Comment: Are you sure that you setup your custom cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath(_:)` and not the default `UITableViewCell`? It can still be an autolayout issue.

Comment: Yes, I used a custom table view cell. If I put it on github, do you have the time to check it out ? If not there's no problem.

Comment: that's an empty project ;)

Comment: Sorry about that. I forgot to push my changes from xcode :) You can look now

Comment: It was autolayout - you didn't have table view constrained to the superview so at runtime it was the same size as at design time - button was there but out of the bounds of the view. I'd suggest studying autolayout first. This is gonna keep happening if you won't do so.

Comment: I was used to UITableViewControllers, thats why I forgot about setting autolayout for tableview. 2 weeks of pain. Thanks :)